# reverse engineering binary file format pattern maker xsd xsp

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, binary-data

I'm new to reverse engineering (especially exe and dll) and trying to break pattern maker and cross-stitch pro file formats of saved patterns *.xsd and *.xsp
I'm saving the same data over and over again and binary data changes every time, even if there is no any changes in file.

For example - there is binary chunk i need to parse - 16 bytes (changes every time, i think this is some kind of header with some kind of key to pack data with bitwise operations) 4 bytes LE number showing amount of 4 byte blocks (changes every time, this might be the actual data)

Data blocks shows region of 4096 cells and if this region is empty - there is always 2 blocks with 4 bytes of data each (maybe coordinates of region)

```
73258713 C65AE979 3A1C9E66 8C41A802(header)

02000000 (LE number of blocks)

FFBBDD30 ED1A1376 (data of empty region)
```

and after saving again i'm having this

```
1D45BB6F 9D571C23 9A42CC53 4F78CD7A(header)

02000000 (LE number of blocks)

5289EC22 33657D7E (data of empty region)
```

Is there any kind of data pack algorithm, that can produce this kind of data? Or maybe there is file specification for cross-stitch data formats anywhere? Searched all over the internet with no result.

Also. There is an application, called myriacross Quick View, that can view all known cross-stitch data formats. Any hint on how to reverse engineer this?

Comment: This data that changes may be something related to some time watermark in the file, if you can try saving a file at the same date and time reajusting the SO clock

Comment: you can also make a Madaline neural network to map this pattern if it is not random, like some checksum or encryption

Comment: @FertoVordalastr, have you found out how to read those stitches data? I have same problem with reading .xsd files and cannot find anything about it.